# my NPC truffle won't move in its house

Tags: terraria-mobile

I don't know why, but I've met all its requirements for the house its on underground it has a chair, a table, a lighting source. I can even hear its background music.Its not near on the corruption. I'm on hardmode and I still didn't defeat the mechanical bosses BUT,the most confusing thing is that it has a statue message that says :Agaric wants to settle down.I really want truffle to move in its house. What should I do???

Comment: "*What should I do???*" You could start with telling us which game you're talking about. It may seem unlikely, but it's not impossible for multiple games to match the same description.

Comment: I'm very sorry but the game is Terraria.I'm new in here.

Answer (score -1):

The mushroom has to be in an above ground mushroom biome (lay down a bunch of mud and drop the mushroom seeds). Then put down a house and he should move in.